# How to import text file data to database using spring and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
Here is my tesseract OCR converted .txt file

    ATITENDANCE SHEET

*Department: @ELECTRONICS *Date: @19/08/ 2017
*Year: @FIRST *Division: @A
*Subject Code: @TM404 *Teacher Code: @10447

@001 @002 @003 @004
@005- @006 @007 @008-
@009 @010 @011- @012
@013 Ieﬂll- @015 @016
«@01-7- @018 @019 mae-
@021 @022 @023 @024
@025 -@-0%6- @027 @028
@029 @030 I903! @032
@033- @034 @035 @036-
@037 @036- @039 @040
@041 @042 @043 @044
@045 @046 @047 .6048-

'@'0|19' @050 @051- @052
@053 @054 @055 @056
-@O§i- @058 @059 @060

@061 I096? @063 m
IGOGE @066 @067 @068
@069 @070 @071 @072
@073 @074 i375- @076
@077 @078 @079 @080



EE—Tahoma-20~B—44
```

So,How can I stored into the database 
Department:ELECTRONICS   Date: 19/08/ 2017
Year: FIRST Division: A
Subject Code: TM404 Teacher Code: 10447
Roll no get auto incremented

Comment: Use Spring Batch - it has full support for importing odd text files with headers, footers and so on.

Comment: @PaulNUK, I am new to spring..can you please elaborate what you are saying!!